# How to access DOM element after binding in knockout?

Tags: knockout.js

I want to access DOM element after binding in knockout.
I want access to tr:first-child

How can I access?? please help me

```js
  $("#account_tab_m2005 table tbody tr:first-child td .popOver").click(function(){
        alert("a");
        $(this).css('z-index',11);
    });

    $("#account_tab_m2005 table tbody tr:nth-child(2) td .popOver").click(function(){
        $("#account_tab_m2005 table tbody tr:first-child td .popOver").css('z-index',10);
        $(this).css('z-index',10);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="account_tab_m2005">
    <table>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: orderArray_tab, visible: orderArray_tab().length > 0">
            <tr>
                <td>...</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: You aren't supposed to access DOM elements that are created by knockout. If you need `click` behavior, you use the `click` binding and an event handler specified in a viewmodel. If you need to update the style, you use the `style` binding or `css`.

Comment: Why not bind directly to the element you want to attach the click handler to?

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to use $index() in your foreach to give the firstChild a different template.  Looks like you are trying to get the first element to change css on it. Just use a different class/id here.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="account_tab_m2005">
    <table>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: orderArray_tab, visible: orderArray_tab().length > 0">
            <!-- ko if: $index() === 0 -->
            <tr id="firstChild">
                <td>...</td>
            </tr>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko if: $index() !== 0 -->
            <tr>
                <td>...</td>
            </tr>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

and

```
$('#firstChild').css('z-index', 11)
```